# Spring 2.0 Redirect from within formBackingObject() method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redirect

So I'm writing a spring 2.0 controller, myNewController.ctl, I've got the request mapping working such that when the user hits a button on a page, the flow of control passes to the `formBackingObject()` method as expected.

Now, at this point business logic requires that sometimes we generate the backing object as normal and return it (which I can do fine), but in other situations, we want to redirect the user to a different controller, (as a get request).

I've tried to do something like

`return new RedirectView("/myOtherController.ctl");`

but The user is never redirected, and the browser just goes to myNewController.ctl and gets an error screen.

How can I redirect the user to a different controller from within the `createBackingObject()` method of a spring 2.0 simpleFormController workflow?

Edit: I do know that there are newer technologies out there, but this is a legacy system and a one-time add-on. Upgrading isn't the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: I hope this is for maintenance of legacy software. Consider upgrading if it is not.

Comment: Yes it is for maintenance of legacy software. Upgrading isn't an option at this time.